# Use pandas to calculate month and week from a given date column in excel and append to another column in same sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working on a pandas program, where i fetch rows from other excel sheets and append them to the main file:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#reading all three ticket excel sheets
df1 = pd.read_excel("sheet a.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("sheet b.xlsx")
df3 = pd.read_excel("sheet c.xlsx")

#Creating Panadas Excel writer using xlsxwriter as engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"main_excel.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl")

writer.book = load_workbook(r"main_excel.xlsx")
sheets = writer.book.sheetnames 
reader1 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet a") 
reader2 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet b") 
reader3 = pd.read_excel(r"main_excel.xlsx", "sheet c")  

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[0], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader1)+1) 
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[2], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader2)+1) 
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =sheets[4], index = False, header = False,startrow=len(reader3)+1)  

writer.save() 
writer.close()
```

After writing the data to the excel file, I have to calculate the month and the week number from the dates in the data and fill in the missing columns.

[image: not the actual data but similar]

The data gets appended each week, so i would to append the data to the pre-existing columns.

is there a way to do that without writing the formula in the excel sheet itself? by coding it in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your date column using the code below:

```
df['Opened'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opened'])
```

Then you can get your other columns using:

```
df['Month'] = df['Opened'].dt.month_name()
df['Week'] = df['Opened'].dt.week
```

Comment: That worked, but how do i append it to a column without overwriting?

Comment: if you do not want to overwrite what is already in the month and year columns, then use a filter to take them off. You can do `df2 = df.loc[df['Month'].isna()]`,  `df = df.loc[~df['Month'].isna()]` to separate them out, then `df = pd.concat([df,df2])`. You would apply the code in the answer to df2 before the concat.